# Using Code Runner I can't run programs in any programming language

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I can't run any program using for example Python C, C++ .
Previously I could but now I don't know what happened . The run button [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqBr9.png) neither does the ctr+alt+n shortcut .

Anyone who knows how to fix that ?

In case you need settings: (*settings.json*)

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "php": "php",
    "python": "python -u",
    "perl": "perl",
    "perl6": "perl6",
    "ruby": "ruby",
    "go": "go run",
    "lua": "lua",
    "groovy": "groovy",
    "powershell": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File",
    "bat": "cmd /c",
    "shellscript": "bash",
    "fsharp": "fsi",
    "csharp": "scriptcs",
    "vbscript": "cscript //Nologo",
    "typescript": "ts-node",
    "coffeescript": "coffee",
    "scala": "scala",
    "swift": "swift",
    "julia": "julia",
    "crystal": "crystal",
    "ocaml": "ocaml",
    "r": "Rscript",
    "applescript": "osascript",
    "clojure": "lein exec",
    "haxe": "haxe --cwd $dirWithoutTrailingSlash --run $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "rust": "cd $dir && rustc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "racket": "racket",
    "scheme": "csi -script",
    "ahk": "autohotkey",
    "autoit": "autoit3",
    "dart": "dart",
    "pascal": "cd $dir && fpc $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "d": "cd $dir && dmd $fileName && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "haskell": "runhaskell",
    "nim": "nim compile --verbosity:0 --hints:off --run",
    "lisp": "sbcl --script",
    "kit": "kitc --run",
    "v": "v run",
    "sass": "sass --style expanded",
    "scss": "scss --style expanded",
    "less": "cd $dir && lessc $fileName $fileNameWithoutExt.css",
    "FortranFreeForm": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran-modern": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran_fixed-form": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "fortran": "cd $dir && gfortran $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
},
"code-runner.ignoreSelection": true,
"workbench.startupEditor": "newUntitledFile",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
"code-runner.languageIdToFileExtensionMap": {

    "bat": ".bat",
    "powershell": ".ps1",
    "typescript": ".ts"
}
```

Comment: Is your `$dir` variable set accordingly? Do you have `gcc` on your `PATH` variable in your OS?

Comment: Yes I do but I can't really figure out what's really wrong [1](https://imgur.com/wyV6Ozi). These settings are correct because I've installed `GCC` in my OS `PATH` variables.

Anything else you would suggest?